# how to join and find value in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

*** hwo to combine these two tables and check the id's which are greater than 1600 for NDAKOTA regions***

1   alaska  robert
2   boston  lilly
3   NDakota Michael
4   NDakota Will
5   NDakota Mark

1A  1   09/09/2012  1200
2A  2   8/9/2016    3400
3B  3   4/5/2016    2300

```
customers = LOAD '/home/vis/Documents/customers' using PigStorage(' ')               AS(cust_id:int,region:chararray,name:chararray);

sales = LOAD '/home/vis/Documents/sales' using PigStorage(' ') 
AS(sales_id:int,cust_id:int,date:datetime,amount:int);

salesNA = FILTER customers BY region =='NDakota';

joined = JOIN sales BY cust_id,salesNA BY cust_id;

grouped = GROUP joined BY cust_id;

summed= FOREACH grouped GENERATE GROUP,SUM(sales.amount);

bigSpenders= FILTER summed BY 1$>1600;

DUMP sorted;
```

recieving errors as

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Apache Pig Docs**

> Use the disambiguate operator ( :: ) to identify field names after
>   JOIN, COGROUP, CROSS, or FLATTEN operators.

Below code snippet should be suffice to achieve the objective, let me know if you see any issues.

```
customers = LOAD 'customers.txt' using PigStorage(' ')  AS(cust_id:int,region:chararray,name:chararray);
sales = LOAD 'sales.txt' using PigStorage(' ') AS(sales_id:chararray,cust_id:int,date:chararray,amount:int);
custNA = FILTER customers BY region =='NDakota';
joined = JOIN sales BY cust_id,custNA BY cust_id;
req_data = FILTER joined BY amount > 1600;
DUMP req_data;
```

Comment: @S123DB8 : can you do a dump after each step and see where data went missing. i.e dump customers, dump sales etc ... I dont see any issue in the code. Can you change the field separator to | or , and try ?

Comment: Can you change the field separator in customer and sales dataset to | ? Looks like spacing issue to me. In code snippet while reading use PigStorage('|')

Comment: data is  storing correctly, there is some issue with my machine it restarts after issuing DUMP req_data. Thankyou .What i have to do if i have large file with spaces ,do i need to replace space with '|' ?

Comment: @S123DB8 :Looks like you had inconsistent separator in input files, in few places it was a single space and in few it was more, this might have caused the issue of not able to read the data correctly. If this answer helped ur question, you can accept it.

Comment: i have only one doubt here, if there is large file with infrequent spaces ,what i have to do ? again do i need to replace space with '|' ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137185/discussion-between-s123db8-and-murali-rao).